# JSTL-unable to display object attribute values in jsp

Tags: java, sql, jsp, servlets, jstl

Software used: Tomcat 8.0.52 , jdk/jre 10.0.1,notepad++ (can't use IDE) 
have set all environmental variables properly and checked it with example programs. 
Trying to display a result of query from servlet to .jsp 
my servlet code:

```
List<User> uu = new ArrayList<User>();    
ResultSet rs;
    rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from assign where userid!='admin';");
    if(!rs.next())response.sendRedirect("displayerror.jsp");
    else{
        do{
            User p=new User();
            p.setuserid(rs.getString(1));
            p.setpassword(rs.getString(2));
            p.setcontact(rs.getString(3));
            p.setrole(rs.getString(4));
            p.setmentor(rs.getString(5));
            p.setgroup(rs.getString(6));
            uu.add(p);
        }while(rs.next());
    }
    request.setAttribute("results", uu);
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("display.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
```

setting the List uu to 'results' and forwarding it to display.jsp where i intend to display the query result.
class USER:

```
class User {
    String userid;
    String password;
    String contact;
    String role;
    String mentor;
    String group;
    // Setters and getters
}
```

objects of this class is passed to display.jsp.
    My display.jsp code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>     
      <html>
           <head><title>WELCOME</title></head>
           <body>
           <form  >
           <table>
            <c:forEach items="${results}" >
            <tr><td><c:out value="${results.userid}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${results.password}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${results.role}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${results.contact}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${results.mentor}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${results.group}"></c:out></td></tr>
            </c:forEach>
            </table>
            </form>
           </body>
     </html>
```

I tried running a basic JSTL program(displaying numbers) and it worked fine. I tried to display just the 'results' size too and it displayed. only case where the code is not working is when I try accessing ${result.userid} where it does not throw any error just a blank screen.
In web.xml :I'm tried with version 3.1 , 2.5 too (if that helps).
Have placed the .jar files (taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar & taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar in class path)
pardon me if there is any fault in answer or code format(my first question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
<c:forEach var="results" items="${results}">
   <tr>  
       <td><c:out value="${results.userid}"></c:out></td>
       <td><c:out value="${results.password}"></c:out></td>
       <td><c:out value="${results.role}"></c:out></td>
       <td><c:out value="${results.contact}"></c:out></td>
       <td><c:out value="${results.mentor}"></c:out></td>
       <td><c:out value="${results.group}"></c:out></td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: It is similar like foreach loop in java. Here  var="results" indicating object for each loop.